# I am using the bash terminal in VS Code, I am new to coding, and the terminal displays very differently, how do I get them to match?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, terminal, format, settings

[here is what it looks like on the course](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhFz4.png)

[Here is what it looks like for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHI68.png)

How do I get it to not show the line "dayne@DESKTOP-323EO95 MINGW64 ~"?

Also, it would help if I could get an explanation as to why it displays this way. Thanks.

I tried looking through the settings on VSCode, and on the bash terminal settings, but couldn't find it. I could be easily just missing it though.

I also searched the internet for solutions, but couldn't find any, since I'm not really sure on the terminology I need to use to find my problem.

Comment: You are talking about bash prompt customization (in terms of what to search for)

Answer (score -1):

You are probably using an `sh` terminal.

The `sh` shell typically presents a minimalist prompt, containing only the $ symbol, while `bash` often displays additional information such as the current username and working directory in its default prompt, making it appear more complex.

To get it to not show the line "dayne@DESKTOP-323EO95 MINGW64 ~", you could change the default terminal in VS Code.